# How can I evaluate an expression with sin, cos and other functions?

Tags: c#, algorithm, expression, evaluation

After doing some research, I learned about the postfix notation, and how to parse an expression.

My code converts to postfix notation, and then it evaluates it using the stack based method. For example:

```
Initial expression: 5 + 2^(4 - 1)
Postfix notation: 5 2 4 1 - ^ + 
Result: 13
```

Now I am trying to expand this program to be able to evaluate expressions with functions, like sin, cos, log, for example: `5 + sin (2 + log (2))`.
My initial idea was, before parsing it, to find these functions, evaluate their results, and replace it in the string. But I don't think it's a very good idea...

So how can I do this in an efficient way?

Here is some code written in c#, if it is of any use: http://pastebin.com/7wB81fyQ, but I would prefer some pseudo-code so that I understand what I am writing better... I'm not one of those guys who just copy and paste.

Comment: Functions (e.g. `sin`, `cos`, etc.) are in **prefix** notation.  You just need to apply a different parsing rule.

Comment: This is all explained by the Shunting-Yard algorithm, here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thank you, I will try this algorithm.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I would have checked this as the answer, but since it's only a comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat these functions like any other operator plus braces. First calculate what's in the braces, then execute the function.

```
Initial: 3 * Sin(4 + 5)
Postfix: 4 5 + Sin 3 *       (that's how I would enter it in a HP calculator)
or:      3 4 5 + Sin *
```

Other than `+`, which consumes two numbers, `Sin` consumes only one number.

Comment: I would not work with strings. There is a nice `Stack<T>` class in `System.Collections.Generics`.

Comment: Yes exactly, but I needed the Shunting-Yard algorithm to generate the correct postfix.